# windows form application list to ADO.NET datatable

Tags: c#, ado.net, linq-to-twitter

This is my first question, please ignore my mistakes. 
I am running a C# project which passes requirements of twitter feed, 5 attributes in a string named "urlAll". I am going to split the properties with *#06# which I declared before which is given bellow.

```
    public DataTable GetTwitterDataTableMulti(string urlAll)
    {

        Trace.bDebug = false;
        if (ExitNow)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string[] allurl = urlAll.Split(new string[] { "*#06#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    return Dt;
    }
```

I have created another project with windows form application using LinqToTwitter and it returns a list. All I need is to return the list as a ado.net table which I have written before. Below is my twitter feed code.

```
    //initializing a list of current news feeds
    private List<Status> currentTweets;

    //parent class of the form application
    //interface
    public TwitterFeed()
    {
        //initializing the components
        InitializeComponent();
        //call the function that will display current 200 feeds from twitter
        GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine();
        //clearing the textbox in which the feeds will be displayed
        lstTweetList.Items.Clear();

        //displaying the feed in text box right
        currentTweets.ForEach(tweet => lstTweetList.Items.Add(tweet.User.Name + ":" + tweet.Text));
        //display follow list in text box left
        //GetSideBarList(GetFollowers()).ForEach(name => lstFollowNames.Items.Add(name));

    }


    //method that gets current 200 feeds form twitter of the user
    private void GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine()
    {
        var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);
        var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                     where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home &&
                     tweet.Count == 200
                     select tweet;
        currentTweets = tweets.ToList();
    }
```

what would be the possible way to integrate them ?

Comment: because I need to pass C# DataTable to a C++ DataTable, then I will insert them into Data base.

Comment: How the two code snippets you shared are related to each other? How the `Status` class look like? Where is your method which returns DataTable in the second code snippet?

Comment: it is related. Because I want to use the 2nd code within the first code. but the 2nd code it has a class and an interface so I can not use a class within another class. 
My point is to use LinqToTwitter library (a Twitter API). 
Status is a default/build in class in LinqToTwitter. I was able to collect live feed from twitter using windows form application which return a list and displayed through listbox. 
now I want to implement the code on a C# class library project which will return a DataTable in stead of a list.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but are you only searching for a way to convert your List to an equivalent DataTable?

Comment: yes. If I find the way to convert list to DataTable that will be enough for to me.

Comment: On another note, LINQ to Twitter is async and you need to call it via async methods. e.g. private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine();
}
async Task GetMostRecent200HomeTimeLine()
    {
        var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);
        var tweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                     where tweet.Type == StatusType.Home &&
                     tweet.Count == 200
                     select tweet;
        currentTweets = await tweets.ToListAsync();
    }

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your list does not have any other collection:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
      {
         DataTable table = null;
         if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
         {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

            List<PropertyDescriptor[]> propList = new List<PropertyDescriptor[]>();

            table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor item in properties)
            {
               if (IsArrayOrCollection(item.PropertyType))
               {
                  continue;
               }
               AddColumnsForProperties(typeof(T).Namespace, null,  table, (new[] { item }).ToList(), ref propList);
            }

            object[] values = new object[propList.Count];

            foreach (T item in list)
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                  values[i] = GetValueFromProps(propList[i], item) ?? DBNull.Value;

               table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
         }
         return table;
      }

  private static object GetValueFromProps(PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors, object item)
  {
     var result = item;
     foreach (var descriptor in descriptors)
     {
        if (result != null)
        {
           result = descriptor.GetValue(result);
        }
     }
     return result;
  }


  private static void AddColumnsForProperties(string myNamespace, string parentName, DataTable dt, List<PropertyDescriptor> p, ref List<PropertyDescriptor[]> properties)
  {
     var pLast = p.Last();

     if (pLast.PropertyType.Namespace != null && pLast.PropertyType.Namespace.StartsWith(myNamespace))
     {
        var allProperties = pLast.GetChildProperties();
        if (allProperties.Count > 0)
        {
           foreach (PropertyDescriptor item in allProperties)
           {
              var newP = p.ToList();
              newP.Add(item);

              string childParentName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentName)
                 ? String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", parentName, pLast.Name, item.Name)
                 : String.Format("{0}.{1}", pLast.Name, item.Name);
              if (item.PropertyType.Namespace != null && item.PropertyType.Namespace.ToLower().StartsWith(myNamespace))
              {
                 AddColumnsForProperties(myNamespace, childParentName, dt, newP, ref properties);
              }
              else if (!dt.Columns.Contains(childParentName))
              {
                 dt.Columns.Add(childParentName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType) ?? item.PropertyType);
                 properties.Add(newP.ToArray());
              }
           }
        }
        else if (!dt.Columns.Contains(pLast.Name))
        {
           dt.Columns.Add(pLast.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pLast.PropertyType) ?? pLast.PropertyType);
           properties.Add(p.ToArray());
        }
     }
     else if (!dt.Columns.Contains(pLast.Name))
     {
        dt.Columns.Add(pLast.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pLast.PropertyType) ?? pLast.PropertyType);
        properties.Add(p.ToArray());
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to test this. I will let you know.